# Method inside class not calling

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm a new python programmer and I'm facing a problem with my class beccause I have 2 functions which are not calling (on_enter) and (on_leave). When I wrote the same application without class format, they were working perfectly. Please for your assisstance.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
import winsound
from winsound import *

class Patients():
    def __init__(self, main):
        lblBackGround = tk.Label(main, bg="white", fg="black", width=1024, height=768)
        lblBackGround.place(x=0, y=0)

        self.btnExit = tk.Button(main, text="X", bg="yellow", fg="black", width=2, height=1, relief="flat", command=self.Exit)
        self.btnExit.place(x=1330, y=50, anchor=CENTER)
        self.btnExit.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.btnExit.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

        self.btnNew = tk.Button(main, text="X", bg="yellow", fg="black", width=50, height=10, relief="flat", command=self.New)
        self.btnNew.place(x=200, y=100, anchor=CENTER)
        #self.btnNew.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
        #self.btnNew.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)


    def PlaceScreen(self):
        WindowWidth = 1366
        WindowHeight = 768
        ScreenWidth = main.winfo_screenwidth()
        ScreenHeight = main.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ScreenWidth/2) - (WindowWidth/2)
        y = (ScreenHeight/2) - (WindowHeight/2)
        main.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (WindowWidth, WindowHeight, x, y))    

    def Exit(self):
        winsound.PlaySound ('Click.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        main.destroy()

    def on_enter(self):
        btnExit['background'] = 'gray'
        winsound.PlaySound ('Hover.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)

    def on_leave(self):
        btnExit['background'] = 'yellow'
        

    def New(self):
        pass


main = Tk()
main.title ("Easy Clinic")
main.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
application = Patients(main)
#main.overrideredirect(True)
#main.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

main.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `on_enter` and `on_leave` methods are trying to refer to `btnExit` as a global, rather than an instance variable.  Change `btnExit` to `self.btnExit`.  Similarly, `Exit` attempts to refer to `main`, which would only work if `main` were a global.  You probably want to set `self.main = main` in your `__init__` method, then refer to `self.main` in `Exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Two minor problems are causing the program to fail.

The first is you are missing self when referencing btnExit in both the `on_enter` and `on_exit` methods

When this fix is applied the on enter and on exit methods look like this:

```
def on_enter(self):
    self.btnExit['background'] = 'gray'
    winsound.PlaySound('Hover.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)

def on_leave(self):
    self.btnExit['background'] = 'yellow'
```

Second when the on_enter and on_exit methods are called they are expected to have both self and event parameters.

With this fix the on_exit and on_enter methods should look like this:

```
def on_enter(self, event):
    self.btnExit['background'] = 'gray'
    winsound.PlaySound('Hover.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)

def on_leave(self, event):
    self.btnExit['background'] = 'yellow'
```

Here is your code refactored:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import winsound


class Patients:

    def __init__(self, main):
        lblBackGround = tk.Label(main, bg="white", fg='black', width=1024, height=768)
        lblBackGround.place(x=0, y=0)

        self.btnExit = tk.Button(main, text="X", bg="yellow", fg="black", width=2, height=1, relief="flat",
                                 command=self.exit)
        self.btnExit.place(x=1330, y=50, anchor=CENTER)
        self.btnExit.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.btnExit.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

        self.btnNew = tk.Button(main, text="X", bg="yellow", fg="black", width=50, height=10, relief="flat",
                                command=self.new)
        self.btnNew.place(x=200, y=100, anchor=CENTER)
        # self.btnNew.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
        # self.btnNew.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

    def place_screen(self):
        WindowWidth = 1366
        WindowHeight = 768
        ScreenWidth = main.winfo_screenwidth()
        ScreenHeight = main.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ScreenWidth / 2) - (WindowWidth / 2)
        y = (ScreenHeight / 2) - (WindowHeight / 2)
        main.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (WindowWidth, WindowHeight, x, y))

    def exit(self):
        winsound.PlaySound('Click.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        main.destroy()

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.btnExit['background'] = 'gray'
        winsound.PlaySound('Hover.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.btnExit['background'] = 'yellow'

    def new(self):
        pass


main = Tk()
main.title("Easy Clinic")
main.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
application = Patients(main)
# main.overrideredirect(True)
# main.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: @TomKarzes while it's true that having the main completely enclosed as a member is better design. Because he never assigns to self.main trying access the Tkinter root through self.main would cause the program to break. Already I have changed more than I should of by changing the code style. It may be his intention to access the tkinter root as a global. As someone more experienced than me you could put up your own answer to show me a better solution.